# OnClick() handler in map function is changing the state of all elements instead of only clicked element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, next.js

I am creating a Next js site mcqs and  answer.
Initially only questions are rendered with the title and options.
There is a button to show the answer of given question but when button is clicked it is changing the state of all elements in the map function instead of element that is clicked.

```
export default function Chapter({ chapter }) {
  const [right, setRight] = useState(false)

  function handleOnClick() {
    setRight(!right)
  }
 <main className='main_q'>
    <h1>{chapter.items[0].name}</h1>
    {chapter.items[0].questions.items.map((question, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={question.id} className='question_container'>
            <div className='question_q_t'>
              <div className='question_q'>Q</div>
              <div className='question_t'>
                <Markdown>{question.title}</Markdown>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='option_container'>
              <div className='option_a_o'>
                <div className='option_a'>A</div>
                <div className='option_o'>
                  <Markdown>{question.optionA}</Markdown>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className='option_a_o'>
                <div className='option_a'>B</div>
                <div className='option_o'>
                  <Markdown>{question.optionB}</Markdown>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className='option_a_o'>
                <div className='option_a'>C</div>
                <div className='option_o'>
                  <Markdown>{question.optionC}</Markdown>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className='option_a_o'>
                <div className='option_a'>D</div>
                <div className='option_o'>
                  <Markdown>{question.optionD}</Markdown>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a
              className='solution_link'
              target='_blank'
              href={`/${question.chapter.subject.category.slug}/${question.chapter.subject.slug}/${question.chapter.slug}/${question.id}`}
            >
              See Solution
            </a>
            <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Answer</button>
            {right && <div>{question.rightAnswer}</div>}
          </div>
        )
      })}
  </main>
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put each question div into its own component, and make a `right` state in *that* component:

```
const Question = ({ question }) => {
  const [right, setRight] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div key={question.id} className='question_container'>
    // etc
```

Or make an array of `right` states in the parent:

```
export default function Chapter({ chapter }) {
  const qs = chapter.items[0].questions.items;
  const [rights, setRights] = useState(qs.map(q => false));
  const makeHandleClick = (i) => {
    setRights(
      rights.map((r, j) => j === i ? r : !r)
    );
  };
  // ...
            <button onClick={makeHandleClick(i)}>Answer</button>
            {rights[i] && <div>{question.rightAnswer}</div>}
```

Comment: And wrap the `Question` component in `memo()`.